# Set Interval to function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, chart.js2

I'm working with Chart.js. I just made an Ajax request so I could get the info from a separate file so I would be able to do a live update on my Chart. I made the data go into my Chart, and now I would need to add an interval to my function, I just don't know-how. 
I would need to update the chart with the function.

```
function callback(response) {
      myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data = response[0];
      myLineChart.data.datasets[1].data = response[1];
      myLineChart.data.datasets[2].data = response[2];
      myLineChart.data.datasets[3].data = response[3];
      myLineChart.update();
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'loadchart.php',
      dataType:"json",
      success: callback
    });
```

What I tried:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
      $.ajax({
      url: 'loadchart.php',
      dataType:"json",
      success: callback
    });
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: One way: you can create a seperate function, wich wraps setInterval() to your callback method.

Comment: @reporter How could I do that?

Comment: No, you need to run the $.ajax() call in the interval. Anyway, wrap the `$.ajax()` call in `setInterval(function () {` and `}, 5000);` for 5 seconds.

Comment: Read this [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) try it yourself first. Post what you have tried.

Comment: @ChrisG I would only need to wrap the ajax request in a separate function?

Comment: Yes, because your callback function is called by jQuery when the request has finished. It doesn't need to go inside the interval function.

Comment: @ChrisG Fortunatly I wrote that is **one** way and not only one ;-)

Comment: @reporter If you're referring to my "No", please note that I was talking to the OP, not you. Otherwise I'd have addressed *you*, like with this comment. In addition, a separate function would indeed be unnecessary if the problem could've been be resolved by `setInterval(callback, 5000);`

Comment: @ChrisG Unfortunately it didn't work for some reason, I'm posting what I tried.

Comment: @ChrisG Would I need to call the function in some way?

Comment: That should work fine, I assume you kept the `callback` function and waited for five seconds? Are you getting any error messages in the console?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I got this: main.php:113 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at callback (main.php:113)

Comment: Hmm. That suggests that `response` is undefined, which seems weird. Use this: https://pastebin.com/u7wK6k4Z and tell us what gets logged.

Comment: @ChrisG From that I doesn't get any errors, but it doesn't update the chart. The response that I get is my arrays

Comment: I accidentally had `setTimeout` in the first paste, do you have `setInterval` instead? Also, if the arrays get logged every 5 seconds and there's no error, the code works as intended. If the chart still doesn't update, the problem is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh I had setTimeout, it still doesn't work, I think is because I set the only the data to update not the labels too, that probably why, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChrisG It worked, Just had to set the labels too